# Two questions about Sappho's name

Tags: etymology, greek, names, alphabets

The [Greek poeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sappho) Ψάπφω/Ψάπφα beared an interesting name, probably not Greek. I have two questions, about the **first** and the **last** letter of her name :

**(1) what was the value of the initial Ψ ?** This letter was later written Σ but I read in a French edition(*) (my translation) :

> Every ancient authors [...] wrote her name with [a Σ]. But when this
>   name appears [in her own poems], it's always written "Psappho" [or
>   maybe Psappha] . [...] However, this written form didn't transcribe a
>   pronunciation beginning with 'ps'. Sappho herself never pronounced her
>   name this way [since she used an old writting system, the 'Egean' one. In
>   this writting system,] one of the signs looks like a right-angled
>   trident and noted one of the consonants used in Asia Minor (a somehow
>   very strong s). [The value of this letter was later misunderstood by
>   the Greeks] who confused it with their psi. [... Same confusion
>   occured in the name of Syrian, written Psyria].

Do other scholars agree with this analyse ? What's the so-called 'Egean' writing system ? **(see my addendum, infra)**

**(2) In her Aeolian dialect, did her name end with -α or with -ω ?** I read in the same edition as above(*) (my translation) :

> When Sappho's name appeared [in her own poems], it's always written "Psappho" or rather Psappha since the Aeolian dialect uses often the a vowel (a long one) where other dialects, and especially the Attic dialect, uses ē or ō.

Do other scholars agree with this analyse ? Are there other Aelion words ending in -ā where Attic has -ē or -ō ?

(*) Edith Mora (1966), Sappho, histoire d'un poète et traduction intégrale de son oeuvre, pages 25-26.

**ADDENDUM** : thanks to Midas and to TKR, I may add a note. As [Edwin L. Brown writes](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/12278/illinoisclassica151991BROWN.pdf?sequence=2), 
"[...] the metrics of the Sapphic pentapody in which Alcaeus invokes Sappho by name tells absolutely against a psi-sound as the original initial in "Sappho.". As Brown points out (same remark [here](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?pid=mhl-001:1951:8::22), page 7), since "Ἰόπλοκ' ἁγνὰ μελλιχόμειδε Σαπφοῖ" (a famous verse composed by Alcaeus) belongs to an Alcaic stanza (× ¯ ˘ ¯ × ¯ ˘ ˘ ¯ ˘ ¯ ), the metric shows that -δε Σα(πφοῖ) is to be read ˘ ¯, the last syllable being not taken in account.

Comment: You can read about the archaic letter in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaic_Greek_alphabets).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a person's name.

Comment: It is a question about historical linguistics.

Comment: Corresponding question on [latin.se]: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/what-was-sapphos-name?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

If I may answer the second of your two interesting questions. As a rule, Aeolic, Doric and some other Greek dialects retain original /ā/ where Ionic and Attic have shifted it to η. This is a famous characteristic of Ionic/Attic. But I cannot think of any examples where Attic ω stands for η in other dialects. There might be examples, but it is certainly not a regular correspondence.

I am not aware that the name (P)sappho has an accepted Greek etymology. In the absence of an etymology this all remains rather speculative.

Comment: "[...] certainly not a regular correspondence" : alas, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the idea of a strong S is possible or better said sḫ-. I find Browns paper on Sappho's name excellent! He suggests that the name is actually Hattian (or similar language), meaning "numinous".

https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/12278/illinoisclassica151991BROWN.pdf?sequence=2

Comment: The idea of the "strong S" originates with an article by Zuntz which can be found [here](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?pid=mhl-001:1951:8::22).

Comment: Midas, TKR : great references, thank you very much. I updated my post.